# How to make all the values in a pandas DataFrame as False?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame (`close`) like this:

[image]

How can I make all the values (including `NaN` and any float number) inside this DataFrame as `False`?

[pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#) doesn't seem to have this ability to achieve my goal.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do with assign

```
df[:] = False
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that it's so easy to do this.